# radius and angle of a sector

Tags: measure-theory

I suspect the answer to the following is incorrect, any guidance would be very much appreciated.

> The Length of a Sector Arc is 20cm. the Area of the Sector is 18cm.
>   Calculate
>
> - the Radius of the Sector
> - the Angle of the Sector in Radians

Here's what I have done;

$$
\begin{split}
A&=18\\
l&=20\\
\mathrm{Area} &= \frac{\mathrm{Radius} \times \mathrm{Arc Length}}{2}\\
18 &= r\times \frac{20}{2}\\
18 \times 2 &= r20\\
36 &= r20\\
36/20 &= r\\
1.8 &= r
\end{split}
$$
Thus, $r = 1.8$ cm.

$$\mathrm{Angle} = 2\frac{A}{r^2} = (2\times 18)/(1.8)2 = 11.1\bar{1} \approx 11.11 \text{ rad}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your sector has radius $r$ and angle $t$. Then length of the arc would be
$$L = 2\pi r \frac{t}{2\pi} = rt = 20$$
and the area would be
$$A = \pi r^2 \frac{t}{2\pi} = \frac{tr^2}{2} = 18$$

You have 2 equations in 2 unknowns, can you take it from here?

**UPDATE**

Multiply the 2nd equation by 2 and we need to solve
$$
\begin{split}
rt &= 20 \\
r^2t &= 36
\end{split}
$$
Clearly, $r \ne 0$ and $t \ne 0$ (otherwise the equations don't hold since LHS of each turns to $0$ while RHS does not). Let's divide the bottom equation by the top one to get $$\frac{r^2t}{rt} = \frac{36}{20} \implies r = \frac{9}{5}.$$

Now that you know $r$, can you solve for $t$?

Comment: I'm still confused, if both equations contain both unknowns, r & t, how would I rearrange to find one of them?

Comment: @Moose see update in my answer